# Access assets folder from non-activity class

Tags: android

I am trying to access the `assets` folder's files from a non-activity class, but I am not able to do it. How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the context to the `NonActivity` class

```
new NonActivity(ActivityName.this);
```

Then in the constructor

```
Context mContext;

public NonActivity(Context context)
{
    mContext = context;
}
```

Then use the context as below

```
InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open(file_path);
```

*Do not create an instance of Activity class. Activity has a lifecycle and is started by startActivity with intent as param.*

Comment: That non activity starts a service, so will this context passed is always available through out when the service runs ?

Comment: @yourkishore that is not a concern. But make sure activity context is within the lifecycle of the activity. Else you might run into memory leaks