# How get a android asset without a activity

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-assets

I have a non visual class that need to read some files from the assets folder.

Is totally out-of-band so don't have a activity. How I can refer to it [without pass down the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875841/access-assets-folder-android-from-non-activity)?

Also I can accept a alternative to the assets way to put files (like .sql) to be read later on the android devices.

P.D:

This is a sample of the code where is called:

```
//Load asset not belong to anyone. Is that radical
let loadAsset(path:string) =
    #if __ANDROID__
    let sr = new StreamReader(?????.Assets.Open(path.Substring(1)))

    seq {
        while not sr.EndOfStream do
            yield sr.ReadLine ()
    }
    #else
    File.ReadLines(path)
    #endif
```

Comment: Edited to remove the F# tag: although your code might be written in F#, unless F# is relevant to your question in some way it's best not to tag the question with the F# tag. In this case, the answer would be the same no matter what language you were writing in.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is a Context. If you application has an Application class, you can use its Context to retrieve asset resources.

It should look something like this:

```
public class App extends Application {
public static Context context;

@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
}
}
```

You can then used App.context to get resources/assets.

Comment: the call to getApplicationContext() is redundant.  This is the application-  it is the application context.  Just store this.

Comment: Also, remember that if you use a custom Application, you need to register the fact in the manifest.

Comment: No, this is not under a Application or any other activity

Answer (score 0):

> How to get an android asset without an Activity

Try using the following code:

```
let sr = new StreamReader(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open(path.Substring(1)))
```